# How to install ubuntu ultimate edition using Wubi?

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I had some trouble installing Ultimate Edition 2.9 on my friend's computer using Wubi. Wubi just doesn't accept installation and gives only 2 options - 'Demo & Install' and 'Learn more'. Tried searching the internet for a solution but couldn't find anything.

Is it Wubi's fault or is it not designed to give support for UE? If latter, what is the alternative to it (without actually giving UE a seperate partition).

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick google search it looks like wubi has never worked for installing Ultimate Linux.